# Preserving values and labels order in pie chart

Tags: r, graph, plot, pie-chart

I'd like to draw a pie chart where the order of values and labels must be preserved. How could I produce it?

It seems that by default R can control for alphabetical and clockwise order. 
I addition, I'd like to add more information to the chart by adding arrows connecting one point to the other of the chart, like from `ABC` to `ZXR`, is it any possible?

```
# Simple Pie Chart
slices <- c(12,11,11,8,6,2,5,3)
lbls <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GPH", "ZXR", "O", "MN", "TS", "ZY")
pie(slices, labels = lbls, main="ranking disk")
```

Thanks,
Eve

Comment: It's best to ask just one question at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will create a pie chart with the labels in the order you posit them, starting at 12 o'clock and going around clockwise:

```
pie(slices, labels = lbls, clockwise=TRUE, init.angle=90, main="ranking disk")
```

You can adapt the `clockwise` and `init.angle` parameters.

Unfortunately, `pie` does not return the coordinates of labels or slices, but you can add arrows by hand if you adapt the coordinates as you need them:

```
arrows(.6,.6,-.6,-.4)
```

[image: pie]

However, you *do* know that pie charts are horrible ways of presenting information, right? The following part of the help page `?pie` is well worth quoting in full:

> ```
>  Pie charts are a very bad way of displaying information.  The eye
>  is good at judging linear measures and bad at judging relative
>  areas.  A bar chart or dot chart is a preferable way of displaying
>  this type of data.
>
>  Cleveland (1985), page 264: “Data that can be shown by pie charts
>  always can be shown by a dot chart.  This means that judgements of
>  position along a common scale can be made instead of the less
>  accurate angle judgements.” This statement is based on the
>  empirical investigations of Cleveland and McGill as well as
>  investigations by perceptual psychologists.
> ```

Comment: if I could, I would give another +1 for the pie-chart quote